# How to get 100 objects from a Set as a collection?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set

`Set s = userIdVsUserInfo.keySet();`

As you can see im taking the keySet from a hashmap userIdVsUserInfo and store it in a Set s. Since the construction of the hashmap is dynamic,the keyset may have more than 100 objects.

how can i get 100 objects as a collection?

Comment: Use an iterator to loop over the set or use: for ('Object in keyset' object : userIdVsYUserInfo.keySet()) and manually add them to a collection.

Comment: Please define "first 100"... any random 100?

Comment: You probably know this already- the first 100 objects which you get will not be in the same order in which you inserted them.

Comment: @joachim ya any random 100 is fine. is there way to do it without using loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `HashMap` doesn't store the elements in order, the first 100 elements you try to get using the `keySet()` may not be actually be the first 100 inserted.

Nonetheless, since you want the result as a `Collection` and without using a loop explicitly, I suppose you can use a `List` in that case

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(userIdVsUserInfo.keySet()); // put the elements into a list
list = list.subList(0, 100); // get a subList with 100 elements
```

And if you're very much concerned about getting a `Set` of 100 elements, you can create a `Set` out of the `List` again, but that's really an overkill.

Answer (score 5):

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could get a stream of keys and limit it to get 100 elements.

```
Set<MyKey> hundredKeys = 
    map.keySet().stream().limit(100).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I don't know what you mean by doing it without looping, there will always be a kind of iteration behind anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can take an iterator from it [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29)

By the way, set is unordered, so there are no "100 first" elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap` is unordered, therefore you can't get the *first 100 pairs*.

Anyhow, you can create a loop from 1 to 100 and fetch the desired amount of pairs,  but note that there will be no order.

Comment: is there anyway to do it without looping? as in using a java function?

Comment: No, at least I am not aware of such. 100 elements is not that much, so you can use loop without any concerns about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use guava's [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) if you're not on java8 and have it in your project

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) { List l = new ArrayList<>(); l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);  l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);    l.add(1);   l.add(1);    l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1); l.add(1);

```
 for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); i += 100;) {
      int j = i + 100;
      if (j > l.size()) {
        j = l.size() + 1;
      }
      List<Integer> l2 = l.subList(i - 1, j - 1);
      System.out.println(l2.size() + ":" + l2);

    }

  }
```

OUTPUT:
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
100:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
81:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Answer (score 0):

Just found another existing utility method:

List<List<YOUR_DATATYPE>> partitions = org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils.partition(yourlist, 100);